# CPU and Memory Profile a .so file

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler, shared-libraries

I have a sample application which uses a library.so(compiled with gcc) file to run. The sample application itself uses few threads and consumes memory while running. I want to profile only the library.so file. But with htop or top command I get the profiling result for sample application and library together. How do I profile the library.so file separately? Thanks.

Comment: If you are building from source, the ``-pg`` option to ``gcc`` while compiling the library, then look at ``gprof``, ummm, assuming gcc.

Comment: Yes I am building from source file using `gcc`. I am going to try what you suggested. Thank you :)

Comment: I have added the option -pg while compiling both the library and sample application. But the `gmon.out` file isn't getting generated.

Comment: I just want to find the cpu and memory consumption of `library.so` nothing else. I don't need function by function profiling.

Comment: Hmm, ``gcc -o maxrand -pg maxrand.c`` and ``./maxrand`` gives a gmon.out here.  Fedora 19 system.  Not sure what to say.